# Multiple 0..1 relations to same table Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am trying to get multiple "units" to have a set of "UnitInfo" assigned but I get the following message from EF when using code first:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   Unit_UnitInfo_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Unit_UnitInfo_Source' in relationship 'Unit_UnitInfo'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
>   SubUnit_UnitInfo_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'SubUnit_UnitInfo_Source' in relationship 'SubUnit_UnitInfo'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

The classes I use looks like this:

```
public class Unit
{
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SubUnit> SubUnits { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UnitInfoId")]
    public UnitInfo UnitInfo { get; set; }
}

public class SubUnit
{
    public int SubUnitId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UnitInfoId")]
    public UnitInfo UnitInfo { get; set; }
}

public class UnitInfo
{
    public int UnitInfoId { get; set; }
    public string Function { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Im sure that it is a simple mistake, I just cant figure it out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are free to mark my solution as answer if it helped solving your problem, or do not hesitate to ask more questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

The `[ForeignKey()]` attribute should refer to either the foreign key, or the navigation property in the same class. So, the UnitInfoId should be a member of the class where you specify the navigation property and the `[ForeignKey()]` attribute.

The navigation properties should be virtual in order to allow EF to create proxy classes for lazy loading. If you do not use fluent api, you should specify the `[Key]` attribute for the primary keys. Furthermore, the reference collections should be declared as virtual ICollection members. The architecture you need can be declared as follows:

```
public class Unit
{
    public Unit()
    {
        SubUnits = new HashSet<SubUnit>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SubUnit> SubUnits { get; set; }

    public int UnitInfoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UnitInfoId")]
    public virtual UnitInfo UnitInfo { get; set; }
}

public class SubUnit
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SubUnitId { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UnitId")]
    public virtual Unit ParentUnit { get; set; }

    public int UnitInfoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UnitInfoId")]
    public UnitInfo UnitInfo { get; set; }
}

public class UnitInfo
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UnitInfoId { get; set; }
    public string Function { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

However, I would recommend using inheritance, since Unit and SubUnit share the same structure. You can read more about EF code first [HERE](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx)